# Where does kabbala write about what time the sabbath ends?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I got a calendar in the mail from some charity. It lists the times to begin and end the sabbath. It's written in Hebrew. Here's this week's:

> **הד״נ**
> 17:02
>
> **מוצש״ק**
> מקובל 18:17
> ר״ת 18:56

That is:

> **candle-lighting [time, before the sabbath]**
> 5:02 p.m.
>
> **the end of the holy sabbath**
> [according to] the kabbalist 6:17 p.m.
> [according to] *Rabenu Tam* 6:56 p.m.

Which kabbalist is this, and where do we see in his writings that he holds of this earlier time for ending the sabbath?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score -1):

It's a mistake. Rabbeinu Tam says to finish it earlier, while the Mekubalim want you to keep Shabbos for Seventy two minutes (in honor of the seventy two letter name of Hashem) after Shabbos